# while installing phpmyadmin getting dependency in ubuntu 12.04

Tags: 12.04, mysql, phpmyadmin

i am newbie in ubuntu/linux system. i am trying to install phpmyadmin and i am getting following error.

```
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:


 phpmyadmin : Depends: php5-mysql but it is not going to be installed or
 php5-mysqli but it is not installable
 Recommends: php5-gd but it is not going to be installed
 E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

i have tried running `apt-get install dist-upgrade` and `sudo apt-get -f install` but didn't help..

i have installed **apache2** and **php5** and **mysql**

can any buddy help to solve this

Thanks in advance

Comment: Did you try updating your repositories? `sudo apt-get update`

Answer (score 0):

Did you install PHP before installing phpmyadmin? Make sure you have a web server software of some sort (such as Apache2) as well as PHP running **before** trying to install phpmyadmin. Phpmyadmin is not an independent software but relies on the functions of other software to perform its functionalities. Most importantly, make sure you have MySQL also installed before phpmyadmin.

Since you are new to web hosting, maybe you should install a package that includes all that stuff. Check out http://vestacp.com for a great package with everything you need. Very easy to install and you can start hosting right away.

Comment: i already have installed apache2 and php5

Comment: As long as you are using official Ubuntu packages (or really any well-made deb-package) it should not be necessary to resolve dependencies manually. Indeed, the OP's error happens when trying to resolve just these dependencies, it is *not* a runtime error. Also, the OP never said that he wants to do webhosting. If he just wants to manage some databases, a complete webhosting package is just overkill.